# How to test android application for different screen sized?

Tags: android

I have finished my application, but I have only 1 real device, and I need to test my application for different screen sizes. So, please, tell me, which emulator configurations should I use for diffrent screen sizes in order to I will be sure that my application will work on each configuration? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there are more than 20 target devices are available in android developer website.
you can download few of them and load those devices in your emulator...
there is option in eclipse to select your target device before running your application...

Comment: Yes I know it, but I need to know which devices is the most popular, then I can test my application for one's

Comment: Its better to check below resolutions.

    320dp: a typical phone screen (240x320 ldpi, 320x480 mdpi, 480x800 hdpi, etc).
    480dp: a tweener tablet like the Streak (480x800 mdpi).
    600dp: a 7” tablet (600x1024 mdpi).
    720dp: a 10” tablet (720x1280 mdpi, 800x1280 mdpi, etc).

Answer (score 1):

Even by using the ADT plugin, in the layout editor, we can select the desired type of the phone, resolution, orientation and can check immediately with different types of resolutions..

Comment: Yes I know it, but I need to know which devices is the most popular, then I can test my application for one's